# Issue with PHP Base Path

Tags: php

Lets take this URLs for example :

```
* http://localhost/amdseo/panel/manage/blogs.php
* http://localhost/amdseo/panel/index.php
* http://localhost/amdseo/panel/features/new/post.php
```

I need them all to include the following file which is located in

```
* http://localhost/amdseo/includes/include.php
```

Is there a code which can lead me to

```
*http://localhost/amdseo/include/include.php
```

no matter on which url i'm currently at?

Answer (score 1):

I usually build my includes like this:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/include.php');
```

This takes you to the document root and you build the path from there.

Comment: While this *should* be set by your web server, you *shouldn't* trust `$_SERVER`

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by "you shouldn't trust `$_SERVER"`?

Comment: This also assumes that all includes are under the document root, which is *evil*!

Answer (score 0):

#### Use this way:

```
$appRoot = "/var/www/amdseo/panel";
include_once "$appRoot/manage/blogs.php";
include_once "$appRoot/index.php";
include_once "$appRoot/features/new/post.php";
```

Comment: The goal is to include one single shared file, not every other file in the project. Also, using `$appRoot = "/var/www...";` is very, VERY maintenance-prone when changing folders. And `dirname(__FILE__)` only refers to the current file's directory, not the shared file's one...

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish a base-folder, from which you can lookup any file below it.
Relentless's option is one way, although I've found that DOCUMENT_ROOT isn't always available or correct.
You can also use the `__DIR__` constant, or `dirname(__FILE__)` if pre-5.4, and use a relative path from that.

For `http://localhost/amdseo/panel/manage/blogs.php` that would work out to the folowing:

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../includes/include.php';
```